# How to open terminal from within a folder using contextual menu?

Tags: macos, terminal, shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

I want to create a shortcut to open a Terminal window from within a folder using contextual menu in Mavericks. What is the procedure to do so?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exact answer for your question, but there is small app in Mac App Store called Go2Shell which adds button to Finder which opens Terminal with path of current folder opened.

Comment: I am using Mavericks. I dragged and placed Go2Sheel in the finder toolbar. But when I click it, it simply opens the terminal but doesn't cd to the current directory in Finder